# Display table inline with other content

Tags: html, css

Why is it that my table won't display inline with other `inline`/`inline-block` content? What's the best fix for this?

This is using `inline-block` or `inline-table` applied to the table.

Note that when you remove either element they display on a line like how you would expect without extra spacing.

```html
<div>
<a class="btn btn-xs">
  down too low
</a>
<table style="display:inline-block;">
<tbody>
  <td>
    <a class="btn btn-xs">
      up too high
    </a>
  </td>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` and `border-collapse: collapse;` on `table`

```css
.btn, .tbl {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tbl {
  display:inline-block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, .tbl {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a class="btn btn-xs">
  down too low
</a>
<table class="tbl">
<tbody>
  <td>
    <a class="btn btn-xs">
      up too high
    </a>
  </td>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Didn't see that padding in dev tools but now that I check again sure enough it's there :-) and completely forgot about border-collapse.